# Can't access bios after legacy boot

Tags: windows, boot, bios

What happened is this:
Basically, I was running Windows 10 on Acer Predator G9-791 and I sort of played around in BIOS.

When I have changed the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy and restarted the laptop, I could only see a somewhat smaller logo on boot that says "(Acer Predator image) Predator", but nothing happens after that.

That would not be a problem if I could just switch the boot mode back to UEFI, the problem is, that after this change to Legacy I can no longer access BIOS with F2, I tried using different keys (del, esc, f1-12) but that didn't work either, please help, what should I do?

EDIT:
When I removed SSD with windows, it booted to some sort of terminal or something and it keeps saying:

> Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083) Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel
>   Corporation.
>
> For Qualcomm Athernos PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.5(03/15/13).
>
> Check the connection!   PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.      No bootable
>
> device -- insert boot disk and press any key

---

### TL;DR: I can't access BIOS anymore after setting my boot system to legacy

Comment: You ahould [edit] your question instead of adding information as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have managed to solve this:

- Remove the SSD/HDD that contains Windows10 boot (or any other boot drive)
- Start the PC and instantly spam F2 key (or whatever is the key to access your BIOS)
- You should now be able to see BIOS.
- In BIOS, Change the boot system back to UEFI (in case the option is no longer there, restore the factory settings of BIOS)
- Shut down PC
- Connect the boot drive
- The PC should now be booted into Windows (or any other OS)

Although, I still do not really know, why I wasn't able to access the BIOS instantly without removing the SSD, but this solution has worked for me

Comment: This solution did not work for me, as the BIOS was still unreachable without the HDD.

Comment: When I press the F2 key nothing happens... This is a nightmare

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with a Lenovo B590. Apparently the keyboard was not handled in legacy mode, making it impossible to reach the BIOS setup menu by pressing F2.

I reset the BIOS in order to set the default configuration again, in which the boot mode was set to UEFI. I was then able to reach the BIOS setup. It can be done in several ways - more info about that here : https://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS

Note : An answer suggested removing the hard drive. It did not allow me to reach BIOS setup.

Answer (score -1):

I found that if you just HOLD the F2 key instead of pressing in when in legacy mode it goes to BOIS instead of Boot manager.